# How Can I Use Enum's Value in React Component

Tags: typescript, react-native

I defined interfaces into common folder, and then I defined an alias for that. I can use other interfaces for type checks but I cannot use enum's value. If there is an import issue or path issue, I couldnt use other interfaces for type checkes, but there is no error about them.

My enum is **RadioGroupPositions**.

[image: Error]

[image: Enum and interfaces]

[image: My component class]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turn the root folder into a local npm package.

1. Run npm pack in the root folder of enum.
2. Copied the gz tarball name given at the end of the terminal.
3. Opened the RadioGroup.tsx file
4. Run npm install ../nameOfTarball
5. In the file, did import {RadioGroupPositions} from package.json